# Entity Framework with Linq, inner Join, Group By, Order By Method syntax

Tags: entity-framework

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(PID.pid) AS Counted,
    (SELECT TOP 1 Collect_id 
     FROM PID_Control  
     WHERE pid_controlY.org_pid = PID_Control.pid) as Collect_id 
FROM 
    PID 
INNER JOIN  
    PID_Control AS pid_controlY ON PID.pid = pid_controlY.pid 
GROUP BY 
    pid_controlY.Collect_id, pid_controlY.org_pid
```

And I want to write the same in Linq, but I'm not sure how to handle this statement:

```
,(select top 1 Collect_id from PID_Control where pid_controlY.org_pid = 
PID_Control.pid) as Collect_id
```

I have done like this, ??? = Wrong line

```
var list = db.PID_Control
            .Include(t => t.PID1)
            .GroupBy(k => new { k.Collect_id })
            .Select(c => new Grouped
                {
                    Collect_id = ???
                    Counted = c.Select(q => q.PID1.pid1).Count(),
                })
               .ToList();
```

How to make that in Linq?

Classes

```
public partial class PID_Control
{
    public int pid_control_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> pid { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Collect_id { get; set; }    
    public virtual PID PID1 { get; set; }
}


public partial class PID
{
    public PID()
    {
        this.PID_Control = new HashSet<PID_Control>();
    }
    public int pid1 { get; set; }    
    public virtual ICollection<PID_Control> PID_Control { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please add your two entity classes and dbcontext class here as well

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you're trying to achieve, but purely looking at the data this should do it:

```
from pc in db.PID_Controls
group pc by new { pc.Collect_id, pc.pid } into pcgrp
select new Grouped
{
    Collect_Id = pcgrp.SelectMany(pc => pc.PID.PID_Controls)
                      .Select(pc2 => pc2.Collect_id)
                      .FirstOrDefault(),
    Counted = pcgrp.Count()
}
```

BTW, do yourself a favor and use plural names for collections (and adhering to other C# naming conventions wouldn't harm either).

Comment: It doesn't work the problem is here: pid_controlY.org_pid = PID_Control.pid, different joins
But I didnt now that you could mix linq Query syntax and Method syntax in same query, Thanks for the tips about the names :)

Comment: What do you mean by "different joins"? By which field are `PID` and `PID_Control` connected?

Comment: By PID pid_controlY.pid = PID_Control.pid